# What's the purpose of SBT implicit imports under Imports tab for build definition module in IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

It's IDEA 13.1 135.1019 here.

I've just noticed there's the `Imports` tab for the build module of a Scala/sbt project.

[image]

It's under `File > Project Structure` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

What's the purpose of the feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are imports, which are visible in `build.sbt` files.

Idea is using its own parser to parse those files, and therefore it needs to know which imports are visible in a context of the file. It is needed when it's building a PSI Tree (which is more or less like an AST Tree, but with extra language specific semantic) to provide syntax highlighting and code completion.

You can do a little test. You cannot add new imports, but you can remove existing. Try removing `Keys._` and highlighting in `build.sbt` for sbt keys should stop working. Interestingly if you have any other plugins, keys belonging to those other plugins should still work.

If you're interesting in details, you can check the [SbtFileImpl](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/master/SBT/src/main/scala/org/jetbrains/sbt/language/SbtFileImpl.scala), and [documentation on PSI Files](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Architectural+Overview#IntelliJIDEAArchitecturalOverview-PsiFiles), and if you feel courageous you could check the documentation on [developing custom language plugins](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA).